# php session.save_path location

Tags: php, unix, webserver, mount

My webserver has 2 mounts on in. The root mount is a 500GB drive, and the web root is mounted to a 2TB raid drive. In my php.ini settings I have been using the default location for sessions "/tmp", but this would mean that the sessions are saved on my 500GB drive not the 2TB drive like all the other website related files.

I am only asking this because the other day I accidently made a backup onto the 500GB drive from a section of my web root, which put it at 100% capacity. Because the 500GB drive was full sessions could not be created in /tmp and users were unable to log in. The issue was resolved and was an accident, so I don't expect to be consistently using 100% of the root drive.

Can anyone give opinions on this?
Does it really matter where sessions are stored (I am running my own dedicated machine)?
Since the web drive is in raid would it put more stress on the drive to manage such a temporary file, considering my raid drive stored highly delivered content?

Thank you.

Comment: You can put them wherever you want

Comment: I know I can put it where ever, the question was considering my setup should the sessions be put on the web mount or the root mount.

Comment: You can put them wherever you like